# Unable to run the android sample code 'bitmapfun'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to run the sample code downloaded from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html.
All I did was download the code and import it like any other sample codes I tried. 
But when I run, 'Unfortunately, BitmapFun has stopped' shows and application exits.

My logcat shows :

```
02-07 13:11:55.647: D/AndroidRuntime(5554): Shutting down VM
02-07 13:11:55.647: W/dalvikvm(5554): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41550ba8)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554): Process: com.example.android.bitmapfun, PID: 5554
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.bitmapfun/com.example.android.bitmapfun.ui.ImageGridActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.bitmapfun.ui.ImageGridActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.bitmapfun-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.bitmapfun-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.bitmapfun.ui.ImageGridActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.bitmapfun-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.bitmapfun-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
02-07 13:11:55.647: E/AndroidRuntime(5554):     ... 11 more
02-07 13:16:55.797: I/Process(5554): Sending signal. PID: 5554 SIG: 9
```

Has anyone ran into similar problems or know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App crashes because it cant find the `ImageGridActivity`. Check your package name in the `manifest` and the `Activity name` also

Comment: Thank you, it was the problem with the build path. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse gets a few things wrong during this import, and you need to fix it manually.

1. After the import, you will notice that there is an error in `res/values-v11`. To fix this, Go to Project Properties of ImageGridActivity and select Android. Check Android 4.4 (API level 19). Then, select Java Build Path. In the Order and Export tab, check Android 4.4. The error in `res/values-v11` should now be fixed and it should build without errors. However, if you try to run the project now, the app will crash with the error described by the OP (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`).
2. During the import, Eclipse mistakenly creates an empty `src` directory and adds it as a source folder on the build path. The source files are actually in the `java` directory, so fix it as follows: Go to Project Properties of ImageGridActivity and select Java Build Path. Under the Source tab, add the `java` folder, and remove the `src` folder. Almost there, but the app will still crash with the same error if you run it.
3. The final step of getting this to work is to add `android-support-v4.jar` to the build path. Again, go to Project Properties of ImageGridActivity and select Java Build Path. Under the Libraries tab, click Add External JARs... and find that jar file. On my system it is at `<home>/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`. Then, go to the Order and Export tab and check `android-support-v4.jar`. That's it.